# Working with capture groups in Elixir

Tags: regex, elixir, phoenix-framework

In the documentation I've not found the description of how to use capture groups in Elixir. How can I do that? Say, I want to extract a substring from a string and replace it with something else:

```
~r"\[tag1\](.+?)\[\/tag1\]"
```

How can I access the string in between `] [/`?

Comment: Please provide your exact string.

Comment: Or just maybe example of what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Regex.run/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html#run/3) for 1 match, [`Regex.scan/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html#scan/3) for all matches, or check out other functions in the [`Regex`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html) module.

```
iex(1)> regex = ~r"\[tag1\](.+?)\[\/tag1\]"
~r/\[tag1\](.+?)\[\/tag1\]/
iex(2)> [_, inner] = Regex.run(regex, "[tag1]bar[/tag1]")
["[tag1]bar[/tag1]", "bar"]
iex(3)> inner
"bar"
iex(4) Regex.scan(regex, "[tag1]bar[/tag1] [tag1]baz[/tag1]")
[["[tag1]bar[/tag1]", "bar"], ["[tag1]baz[/tag1]", "baz"]]
```

Comment: it finds only the 1st ocurrence, how can I find all of them?

Answer (score 1):

The docs do a good job at hiding it, but it's there: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.0.5/Regex.html#replace/4

> The replacement can be either a string or a function. The string is used as a replacement for every match and it allows specific captures to be accessed via \N or \g{N}, where N is the capture. In case \0 is used, the whole match is inserted.

Note: the `\` in `\N` needs to be escaped so it will be `\\N`

Use `Regex.replace/4` (or `String.replace/4` when piping because the string is the first argument) to do this with one command.

You do not actually need to capture what is in between`] [\` in the first place. You only need to match and replace it. This solution uses a "lookaround" which you can find more information on here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

```
iex(1)> String.replace("[tag1]foo[/tag1]", ~r"\w+(?=\[)", "bar")               
"[tag1]bar[/tag1]"
```